# How to run a fortran program using ifort compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, fortran, intel-fortran

Recently, Intel released Ifort compiler for free, for everyone to use. As I have been using gfrotran for quite some time, I decided to install it. I installed the two packages that intel says they are needed (using Windows 10). In the console, as ifort was not recognised (I tried to set up the path to the executable ifort.exe to no avail), i decided to use intel one api tool console.

In that console, ifort is recognised, and you can acces help options and the likes. However, when I try to run a simple test program, it runs with fatal error LNK1104, where imageHlp.lib is missing.

I also tried to run it form the VS17 interface, but it was futile.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and Intel support forums are in permanent "we are experiencing network issues".

I just want to compile a text file to an executable, no libraries involved, nothing fancy.

Comment: There is a setenvironment script that needs to be run on Linux...

Comment: I have VS19 with Intel OneAPI HPC toolkit installed on my Windows 10 machine. It works like a charm. I even didn't install the base toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

I am not seeing any issue with the Intel forums. Make sure you have configured VS2019 for the "C++ Desktop Workload" - see https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html  Or for VS2017, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-fortran-compilers-for-windows-integration-into-microsoft-visual-studio-2017

After you have installed the oneAPI HPC Toolkit, there is a shortcut created Intel oneAPI > Intel oneAPI command prompt. Use this to establish the environment. But you will probably find that the default directory with that shortcut is C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI, which is unusable for compilation, so "cd" to a writable directory. (I like to copy that shortcut to my desktop and modify the "Start in" location.)